# REMOVE property not set during SetupComplete after MSI uninstall

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm working on an InstallShield project of type Basic MSI. There's a Readme checkbox on the final `SetupComplete` dialog. I tried to add a condition `REMOVE<>"ALL"` in the `Show` condition for the checkbox and associated label. It's not working to prevent the Readme checkbox from appearing during an uninstall. I added a textbox bound to the REMOVE property to the same dialog and it's empty after an uninstall.

1. Why is the REMOVE property empty during SetupComplete, even after uninstall?
2. What is a good way to prevent the readme box from appearing after an uninstall?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the REMOVE property empty during SetupComplete, even after uninstall?

[REMOVE=ALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is not available before installvalidate sequence. More on that is over here: [Conditioning Actions to Run During Removal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368013(v=vs.85).aspx)

> What is a good way to prevent the readme box from appearing after an uninstall?

Your approach is correct. Set for your checkbox and corresponding text `Show` condition to `NOT Installed` (First time installation). More on different types of conditions see [Common MSI Conditions Cheat Sheet](https://resources.flexerasoftware.com/web/pdf/archive/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf)

Comment: I don't think this problem is happening before InstallValidate. I think it's happening after InstallFinalize (after the whole exec sequence). Why would REMOVE not be set after the Exec Sequence is done? Also, I confirmed that the Installed property is set at this point after uninstall. But we also want to display the readme file after upgrade. So using the Installed property would not work in that case, right?

Comment: UI sequence happen before InstallValidate (1400 sequence number), which is in execution sequence; for example SetupProgress dialog is 1240 (REMOVE will not be available). Now SetupCompleteSuccess (-1) is something happen after execution sequence (InstallFinalize) where most of the variables are garbage collected and not available.

Answer (score 0):

I learned from http://www.itninja.com/question/remove-the-setupcompletesuccess-dialog that the SetupCompleteSuccess dialog is in its own sequence that does not receive many variables that were available in other sequences. From that page, someone commented:

> I believe the execution order of an MSI during a standard installation
>   looks something like this:
>
> InstallUISequence (LaunchConditions -> ExecuteAction) -> Immediate
>   "InstallExecuteSequence" (LauchConditions -> InstallFinalize) ->
>   Deferred "InstallExecuteSequence" (InstallInitialize ->
>   InstallFinalize) -> Immediate "InstallExecuteSequence"
>   (InstallFinalize -> End) -> InstallUISequence (ExecuteAction -> End)
>
> It would seem that properties set during "InstallExecuteSequence" are
>   not available in the final (post-"ExecuteAction") part of the
>   "InstallUISequence".

That page also suggests using the `_IsMaintenance` property will work as an alternative to the REMOVE property that isn't available at that stage. So I'm using `_IsMaintenance <> "Remove"`